# Sonar rule: Lambdas should be replaced with method references

Tags: java, sonarqube

currently im testing some new sonar rules. With the new sonar rules a new code smell has appeared. "Lambda should be replaced with method references".
I think the rule is quite cool, but with 1 case i have some issues
I'll give an example and maybe someone can explain this case:

Currently a call looks like this:

```
rxTransaction( () -> new SubscriptionJavaLite( subscription ).toSubscription());
```

My first naive thought (and also the suggestion of Intellij) was to use the following methods reference:

```
rxTransaction( new SubscriptionJavaLite( subscription )::toSubscription);
```

So Sonar was satisfied and everything looks the same . But it is no longer equivalent because the `new SubscriptionJavaLite` is executed at different times:

Case 1 runs rxTransaction -> new SubscriptionJavaLite

Case 2 executes new SubscriptionJavaLite -> rxTransaction. Almost earlier.

Is it possible to solve the case differently? Is this finding just a mistake from the sonar rule?
Now I do not want to write SupressWarning over the cases everywhere.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Thanks for these very usefull comments. 
@SirWayne Could you provide the version of SonarJava that you are using in your SonarQube instance and the rule key?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply :).

The rule is squid:S1612
SonarQube is 6.7. 
SonarJava 5.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a case which is not handled correctly by implementation of rule [squid:S1612](https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/coding_rules?open=squid%3AS1612&rule_key=squid%3AS1612).

I would advise you to mark this as a False Positive (FP) and not fix it. Like you correctly mentioned, both cases are not at all equivalent and the rule should therefore not raise an issue here. For more details about why these cases are not equivalent, refer to [JLS §15.13 - Method Reference Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13).

The following ticket will fix implementation: [SONARJAVA-2763](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-2763)